# IIS Reset is required

Tags: iis7

1) I am getting a server activation error frequently. After IIS reset my site works fine. Can anyone guide regarding on this issue?

> `system.servicemodel.serveractivation` error

2) I am getting

> `407 proxy authentication`

error while trying to access `jquery1.10.2.min.js` hosted by Google API

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you explain the #1 a bit more? Perhaps the application pool might be running under a user with lower access.
2. (Solved) Just download a copy of the JavaScript file and keep it in the style library. Then it is inside the site. So you can access it easily. This can be due to a security reason as transferring JavaScript across internet is unsafe.